# String.repeat() should not work being method of nothing?

Tags: string, function, object, methods, repeat

At the console, repeat is not a Symbol of String(), nor of Object nor of Function.
But why does it work with String (String.repeat) ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">   "use strict";
   console.log("dad".repeat(3)); // Retourne "daddaddad"
   console.log("luyluy".repeat(0)); // Rend chaîne vide.
</script>
```

Comment: It is a method of String: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat

Comment: When I check the console in Chrome, `repeat` is indeed a method of String objects. What browser are you using?

Comment: I used Firefox I think version 64